# Generate a new array that groups by key and gets a SUM of another key

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to take the following array and generate a new array that will group all identical keys with the same ID while getting a SUM of the views and grabbing the last DATE only.

**Original Array**

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
        [id] => 10
        [views] => 276
        [date] => 2012-01-30 10:55:00
        [total] => N
    )
[1] => Array (
        [id] => 40
        [views] => 287
        [date] => 2012-01-27 10:00:29
        [total] => Y
    )
[2] => Array (
        [id] => 40
        [views] => 824
        [date] => 2012-01-29 14:40:45
        [total] => Y
    )
[3] => Array (
        [id] => 42
        [views] => 723
        [date] => 2012-01-28 20:15:58
        [total] => N
    )
[4] => Array (
        [id] => 43
        [views] => 428
        [date] => 2012-01-28 17:14:31
        [total] => N
    )
[5] => Array (
        [id] => 45
        [views] => 174
        [date] => 2012-01-20 18:01:11
        [total] => N
    )
)
```

**New Array**

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
        [id] => 10
        [views] => 276
        [date] => 2012-01-30 10:55:00
        [total] => N
    )
[1] => Array (
        [id] => 40
        [views] => 1111
        [date] => 2012-01-29 14:40:45
        [total] => Y
    )
[2] => Array (
        [id] => 42
        [views] => 723
        [date] => 2012-01-28 20:15:58
        [total] => N
    )
[3] => Array (
        [id] => 43
        [views] => 428
        [date] => 2012-01-28 17:14:31
        [total] => N
    )
[4] => Array (
        [id] => 45
        [views] => 174
        [date] => 2012-01-20 18:01:11
        [total] => N
    )
)
```

Comment: what about the "total" field?

Comment: that something I added while trying to do this myself. Total with the value Y meant it was a multiple ID and to total that element. I kinda gave after that wasn't working. Will defiantly try what you posted as an answer.

Comment: I didn't test it, but it will at least give you a starting point. (then again, it could just work as-is :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function last($a, $b) {
  if (strtotime($a) > strtotime($b))
    return $a;
  else
    return $b;
}

$new_array = array();
foreach ($original_array as $data) {
  if (array_key_exists($data['id'], $new_array)) {
    $new_array[$data['id']]['views'] += $data['views'];
    $new_array[$data['id']]['date'] = last($new_array[$data['id']]['date'], $data['date']);
  } else
    $new_array[$data['id']] = $data;
}
$new_array = array_values($new_array);
```

Comment: Beautiful ... I thank you so very much! Worked like a charm and fast. I was worried about the parsing as there are some many of them filter, not the case. Thanks again